# How to dynamically constraint cell contentView's inside subViews?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

In the collectionCell's conentView, I want to constraint the vertical subview with different height according to different values, but the problem is the height is changed unexpectedly when the content is scroll off the screen, then scroll back on the screen:

**The initial and correct view height:**
[image]

**Scroll off the screen, then back (the view height is changed for unknown reason):**
[image]

Below is the layout code:

```
    let contentView = cell.contentView
    let row = indexPath.row
    
    //calculate view height: relativeHeight value
    let cellHeight = cell.frame.height
    var relativeHeight = 0.6 * cellHeight
    
    let values = [112.0, 116.0, 86.0, 95.0, 67.0, 76.0, 34.0, 43.0, 24.0, 35.0, 47.0, 66.0, 66.0, 57.0, 36.0, 64.0, 23.0, 22.0, 23.0, 22.0, 22.0, 22.0, 20.0, 23.0]
    
    let Δvalue = values.max()! - values.min()!
    
    let value = values[row]
    if Δvalue != 0 {
        let different = value - values.min()!
        let ratio = CGFloat(different / Δvalue)
        relativeHeight = ratio * relativeHeight
    }
    
    if contentView.subviews.count == 0 {
        //time label
        let timeLabel = UILabel()
        timeLabel.tag = 3
        timeLabel.textColor = self.textColor
        timeLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        contentView.addSubview(timeLabel)
        
        timeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            timeLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
            timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor)
        ])
        
        //vertical view 
        let valueView = UIView()
        valueView.tag = 1
        valueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue.withAlphaComponent(0.382) //1-0.618
        
        contentView.addSubview(valueView)
        
        valueView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //valueView.constraints.forEach{ $0.isActive = false }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            valueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            valueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            valueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeLabel.topAnchor, constant: -4),
            valueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: relativeHeight)
        ])
        
        //value label
        let valueLabel = UILabel()
        valueLabel.tag = 2
        valueLabel.textColor = self.textColor
        valueLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        contentView.addSubview(valueLabel)
        
        valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            valueLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: valueView.topAnchor, constant: -4),
            valueLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: valueView.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
```

How can I solve such layout constraints problem?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: `valueView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: relativeHeight)` how you are calculating `relativeHeight`? Also any special reason for deactivating constraints before adding them in statement `valueView.constraints.forEach{ $0.isActive = false }`, are you keeping reference of `valueView` in cell? any chance not to create it if there is an existing `valueView`?

Comment: Pls see the relativeHeight calculation supplement. I thought it may be the conflict of constraints caused the view height change, so I try to deactivate first, then activate. Every cell has its own or independent valueView, it's not keeping a reference that can be used by other cell.

Comment: calculation for `relativeHeight` seems to be okay to me, since you are allocating a new instance of `valueView` each time the code is executed, i guess no need for `valueView.constraints.forEach{ $0.isActive = false }`. ONE BIG QUESTION, when where this code is executed? Is it `cellForRow(:indexPath)` or any life cycle method of `UITableViewCell`? It will be hard to debug in that way, can you create one sample project with the issue and share it on github, it will great to check further.

Comment: It's in cellForRow(:indexPath) . Pls download the code at "https://github.com/steve880925/CollectionView-Bug"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue was because not having reference of `valueView` or the `heightConstraint` you are trying to set after allocation, checking `contentView.subviews.count == 0`. The way you are preparing the view hierarchy for the `UICollectionViewCell`, might not be a good practice at all. While dequeuing reusable view, every condition must be covered to set dynamic values. Here there was not any handler if `contentView.subviews.count == 0` fails.

*Fix was done using subclass `UICollectionViewCell` to abstract all the view related task inside `CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell`. I added one property `valueViewHeightConst` with initial constraint value as 0.0. I am setting the exact value after calculation of the height value to set.*

Also introduced one cache mechanism where you do not need to calculate the `relativeHeight` each time the cell is dequeued.

Please check the final project at https://github.com/sauvikapple/StackoverflowAnsToQ63743769.

#### Here is the result

[image]